# PubSub topic does not pull data from cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying web **scraping** though cloud function->PubSub--> BigQuery

I wrote a python code and I deployed my code to cloud functions. Text results of this code turn "ok" and I can see crawled data on logs. But when ı tried to pull messages from topic I could not get any data. When ı check PubSub Api metric I see 404 reponse. How shoul I write the code that publish messages to PubSub topic?

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}`
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path("tokyo-ring-<secret>", "webscraping")
    html_text = requests.get('https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el?take=50').text

    #print(html_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')
    models = soup.find_all('tr', class_='listing-list-item pr should-hover bg-white')
    for model in models:
        model_name = model.find('td', class_='listing-modelname pr').text
        title = model.find('td', class_='horizontal-half-padder-minus pr').text
        model_year = model.find('td', class_='listing-text pl8 pr8 tac pr').text
        price = model.find('td', 'pl8 pr8 tac pr').text.replace('TL','').replace(' ','').replace('.','')
        publish_date = model.find('td', class_='listing-text tac pr').text
        location = model.find('div', style='display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:81px').text.split(' ', 1)[0]
        data= "{"+"\"model_name\":\""+model_name+"\""+","+"\"title\":"+"\""+title+"\",\""+"model_year\""+":\""+model_year+"\""+",\"price\":\""+price+"\""+",\"publish_date\":\""+publish_date+"\","+"\"location\":\""+location+"\"}"
        #pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the publisher.publish() function in your code snippet and that's how you would publish messages to PubSub. Here is a full example showing how you can publish to pubsub:

```
"""Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic with an error handler."""
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# TODO(developer)
# project_id = "your-project-id"
# topic_id = "your-topic-id"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
publish_futures = []

def get_callback(publish_future, data):
    def callback(publish_future):
        try:
            # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
            print(publish_future.result(timeout=60))
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")

    return callback

for i in range(10):
    data = str(i)
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data.encode("utf-8"))
    # Non-blocking. Publish failures are handled in the callback function.
    publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)

# Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher